# css cursor:pointer won't display after it is declared

Tags: html, css

[image][image]([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/npnxhypn/))

I have tried mutiple times, but the cursor fails to display correctly.

I've tested on chrome, safari, and firefox.

What am I missing?

[edit] THANS FOR THE COMMENTs, the screenshot here show that, the mouse is still arrow, it really confuse me now.

```css
.body {
  position: relative width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2em;
}
button {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.rgba {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.regular {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.test:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <button class="transparent">transparent button // no pointer</button>
  <button class="rgba">rgba button // no pointer</button>
  <button class="regular">regular button // no pointer</button>
  <div class="test">regular div // no pointer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buttons will show always with `cursor:pointer`and it's working ok... if you want to NOT have `cursor:pointer`you may need to use `cursor:default` Your fiddle is working as expected

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache before testing? I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: or be sure you don't have any element (maybe absolut positioned) over your buttons

Comment: as you can see in the fiddler, there are no other element at play, and i don't think is a browser problem b/c it happen to me on multiple browser.  if anyone have any ideas as how it happen please let me know.

Comment: Working fine for me in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE

Comment: I added some screen shot, please take a look, I cleared cached, and still the same.

Comment: Well it's definitely an issue with your computer, not with the code, so there's nothing we can really do to help you. Try restarting the computer.

Comment: `cursor:pointer`shows a hand, so what is really the issue?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor @dippas according to this, it should show hand like links do, no?

Comment: Your code does show the hand, on all 4 boxes, in all major browsers.

Comment: let me restart my computer, this sh*t is weird... thanks everyone

Comment: ok, now it work, after I restarted, oh wow... I don't get this, thanks everyone.